# Date String not matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660550/pattern-matching-against-regex-strange-behaviour-scala/) to define a function that returns 0 if a string matches a pattern, 0 otherwise:

```
def verif (s:String): Int = {
 val p = """[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[0-9]{9}""".r
 s match {
 case p(item) => 0  
 case _ => 1
 }
}
```

When I execute:

```
verif("2019-07-01 00:00:00.000000000") // Returns 1
```

I verified my regex on multiple online testors ([here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) or [here](https://www.regextester.com/97070)) and it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined 3 capturing groups, hence you must pattern match three groups. However, it makes sense to just use **non-capturing** groups and the code like:

```
def verif (s:String): Int = {
  val p = """[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]{9}""".r
  s match {
    case p() => 0  
    case _ => 1
  }
}
println(verif("2019-07-01 00:00:00.000000000"))   // => 0
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/MOZ5520)

Note you also need to escape the dot to match a literal dot.